# Cleaning up javascript dom script?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi is it any better way or (cleaner way) to create dom elements? like in an array or something?

example code:

```
$hubbe.toolbarLeft = document.createElement('DIV');
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.setAttribute('id', 'toolbar-left');
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.width = '50px';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.height = '100%';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.position = 'fixed';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.left = '0';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.color = 'white';
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.style.textAlign = 'center';
document.body.appendChild($hubbe.toolbarLeft);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries and frameworks that can help you with that, such as jQuery. If you're sticking to vanilla JavaScript, you can simplify a little bit by setting properties in bulk via `Object.assign()`:

```
Object.assign($hubbe.toolbarLeft.style, {
    width: '50px',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    left: '0',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
});
```

Comment: thank you! that object.assign was exactly what i was looking for :)